# Why is my gcc not in /usr/bin/gcc, even though Xcode 4.3 is installed?

Tags: xcode, gcc, xcode4.3

I installed Xcode 4.3 on my machine, but nonetheless, it isn't anywhere, even a

```
find / -name gcc
```

doesn't reveal it. Still, Xcode can compile C code. So there must be a compiler on my system!

Where is it?

Comment: try `which gcc`, what does it say?

Comment: nothing. there comes a new line

Comment: Could you please accept the answer that worked for you?

Answer (score 7):

In the new version of Xcode 4.3, command line tools are optional and are not installed automatically. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/1006-SW2) for more info:

> **Command-Line Tools Are Optional**:
>   The command-line tools are not bundled with Xcode 4.3 by default. Instead, they can be installed optionally using the Components tab of the Downloads preferences panel as shown in Figure 3.

So you have to go to the **Downloads Preferences** panel and download them.